# How to copy a cloud cockroachdb cluster to a local cluster in a docker container

Tags: docker, cockroachdb, cockroachcloud

I have a cluster running on cockroachlabs that I want to copy to a single-node running in a local docker container. I have searched wide to find how to backup and restore my data.
Since `cockroach dump` has been deprecated, the preferred method seems to be using cloud backups. I have created such a backup in an S3 bucket.

Now, when I connect to my cockroachlabs cluster and type in `SHOW BACKUPS IN '{S3_URI}'`, I get a 1 row result, meaning the backup was found.

When I connect to my local cluster and type the exact same command, I get no result.

I know I could export the tables one by one to csv format, but there has to be a more convenient way.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried just a normal [restore from s3](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/restore.html)? `RESTORE FROM LATEST IN 's3://{bucket_name}?AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID={key_id}&AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY={access_key}';`

Comment: Yes, I have also tried RESTORE FROM LATEST IN {S3_URI}, but the backup is not found. I will try this again later and include the actual output in the question. This is relevant information.